# conda update anaconda Fails | ClobberError

Tags: python, ubuntu, terminal, anaconda

I am trying to update all conda packages.

Tried running these command

> conda update anaconda
>
> conda update --all

But getting this error after confirming on most of the packages.

How to solve and update all the packages ?

```
ClobberError: The package 'defaults::pip-10.0.1-py36_0' cannot be installed due to a
path collision for 'lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_vendor/urllib3/util/__pycache__/wait.cpython-36.pyc'.
This path already exists in the target prefix, and it won't be removed
by an uninstall action in this transaction. The path is one that conda
doesn't recognize. It may have been created by another package manager.


ClobberError: The package 'defaults::pip-10.0.1-py36_0' cannot be installed due to a
path collision for 'lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_vendor/urllib3/util/connection.py'.
This path already exists in the target prefix, and it won't be removed
by an uninstall action in this transaction. The path is one that conda
doesn't recognize. It may have been created by another package manager.


ClobberError: The package 'defaults::pip-10.0.1-py36_0' cannot be installed due to a
path collision for 'lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_vendor/urllib3/util/request.py'.
This path already exists in the target prefix, and it won't be removed
by an uninstall action in this transaction. The path is one that conda
doesn't recognize. It may have been created by another package manager.


ClobberError: The package 'defaults::pip-10.0.1-py36_0' cannot be installed due to a
path collision for 'lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_vendor/urllib3/util/response.py'.
This path already exists in the target prefix, and it won't be removed
by an uninstall action in this transaction. The path is one that conda
doesn't recognize. It may have been created by another package manager.


ClobberError: The package 'defaults::pip-10.0.1-py36_0' cannot be installed due to a
path collision for 'lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_vendor/urllib3/util/retry.py'.
This path already exists in the target prefix, and it won't be removed
by an uninstall action in this transaction. The path is one that conda
doesn't recognize. It may have been created by another package manager.


ClobberError: The package 'defaults::pip-10.0.1-py36_0' cannot be installed due to a
path collision for 'lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_vendor/urllib3/util/selectors.py'.
This path already exists in the target prefix, and it won't be removed
by an uninstall action in this transaction. The path is one that conda
doesn't recognize. It may have been created by another package manager.


ClobberError: The package 'defaults::pip-10.0.1-py36_0' cannot be installed due to a
path collision for 'lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_vendor/urllib3/util/ssl_.py'.
This path already exists in the target prefix, and it won't be removed
by an uninstall action in this transaction. The path is one that conda
doesn't recognize. It may have been created by another package manager.


ClobberError: The package 'defaults::pip-10.0.1-py36_0' cannot be installed due to a
path collision for 'lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_vendor/urllib3/util/timeout.py'.
This path already exists in the target prefix, and it won't be removed
by an uninstall action in this transaction. The path is one that conda
doesn't recognize. It may have been created by another package manager.


ClobberError: The package 'defaults::pip-10.0.1-py36_0' cannot be installed due to a
path collision for 'lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_vendor/urllib3/util/url.py'.
This path already exists in the target prefix, and it won't be removed
by an uninstall action in this transaction. The path is one that conda
doesn't recognize. It may have been created by another package manager.


ClobberError: The package 'defaults::pip-10.0.1-py36_0' cannot be installed due to a
path collision for 'lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_vendor/urllib3/util/wait.py'.
This path already exists in the target prefix, and it won't be removed
by an uninstall action in this transaction. The path is one that conda
doesn't recognize. It may have been created by another package manager.
```

Comment: Did you ever run `pip` commands?

Comment: i have updated all pip packages , after updating when i try to update i get same error.

Comment: Yeah, you should not use `pip` to update `pip` within conda. You should use conda to update everything. I'm afraid you'll probably have to uninstall pip and possibly urllib3 and reinstall them with conda.

Comment: actually i did update `pip` after getting conda errors. Initially i wasnt getting errors while updating , my connection disconnect multiple times when after that upon updating i get these errors. After getting these error - I updated pip though. Is there any way to clean the corrupted packages using anaconda

Answer (score 23, accepted):

```
conda clean --all
conda update --all
```

Worked for me.
I needed to run update command multiple times to update all packages.

Comment: would be nice if the error provided this information instead of the impenetrable `ClobberError`!

Comment: After clearing up the ClobberError I had to clear up a SafetyError: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57151111/conda-safetyerror-file-has-an-incorrect-size

Comment: What exactly causes this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to update conda, particularly if you are using an HPC cluster conda so you don't have write permissions. You only need to clean any previously failed installations with

```
conda clean --all
```

Answer (score -1):

If you need to update all packages, the command is:.

```
conda update --all
```

Comment: Can you try to remove pip and reinstall?