# Conda SafetyError: file has an incorrect size

Tags: python, anaconda

When creating a Conda Environment using `conda create -n env_name python=3.6`, I received the warning below.

```
Preparing transaction: done
Verifying transaction: \ 
SafetyError: The package for python located at /anaconda3/pkgs/python-3.6.8-haf84260_0
appears to be corrupted. The path 'lib/python3.6/distutils/unixccompiler.py'
has an incorrect size.
  reported size: 14583 bytes
  actual size: 14902 bytes

done
Executing transaction: done
```

As the error message states, only Python 3.6.8 file is corrupted, no warning when using `conda create -n env_name python=3.6.3`.

Questions:

- I haven't touch this compiler file. What are the typical reasons for such corruption?
- How to fix this corruption without reinstall Conda?

Comment: conda install -f packaging i would suggest trying this

Comment: The warning happens during env creation, which is not related to package installation. @AnkushRasgon

Comment: I have the same issue happening for "r-base" while cloning packages from one env to another env.

Comment: Just had this happen on installation, when creating new environment from `environment.yml` file.

Answer (score 9):

While the `conda clean -a` ([1](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/commands/clean.html)) command will

> Remove index cache, lock files, unused cache packages, and tarballs.

This did not resolve the `SafetyError` when the `conda create` command was repeated.

Instead, the offending directory was removed using:

```
/bin/rm -rf /anaconda3/pkgs/python-3.6.8-haf84260_0
```

The content was downloaded when the `conda create` command was repeated.